# Put PHP files toghether

Tags: php

Is there a tool to take a `PHP` file, with all its dependencies to other external `PHP` files, and create one, huge, final `PHP` file that includes them all?

Thanks

Comment: Just curious why you want to do this?

Comment: Because I have a library that is a made of many PHP files, and when I update it, it would be easier to replace just one file.

Comment: It will reduce maintainability and remove the ability to take advantage of lazy loading...  So while it seems like a nice idea, in practice it's likely more trouble than it's worth...

Comment: @Marco this is an interesting idea, but bear in mind that a huge file takes time to load, and eats up memory, whether you use all its functionality or not.

Comment: @Marco If you think merging the entire library into one file every time you update would be easier than dealing with multiple files, you must be over complicating things somehow...

Comment: This is what version control is for. "svn update", "git pull", etc.

Comment: @ircmaxell The idea is to use that just for deployment. Locally I'd have my normal file structure. It will reduce time updating the library on different servers.

Comment: @ceejayoz I use svn for development, but I really hate the idea of having many ".svn" folders in production.

Comment: @Pekka actually the library is made in a way that every source is loaded at first execution in any case.

Comment: @Marco: Why do you "really hate the idea of having many .svn folders in production"?  As long as you setup your server to ignore `.svn`, what does it matter (especially since it enables you do track changes on the server by doing an `svn status`, and rapid deployment)...  Honestly, this seems more to me like a solution seeking a problem...

Comment: @Marco Then use "svn export" to check out the code without any `.svn` folders. They do no harm, though.

Comment: @ircmaxell It could the best solution, but not in this case where I'm not allowed to install third-party services, like svn, on the servers. It's so simple to do what I need to do that a new service up and running on server wouldn't be required. I was just wondering if there was an existing solution instead of building my own.

Comment: You don't have to run a svn server, just the client. SVN is as much of a third-party item as PHP is, anyways.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really want to take a whole library and put it in a single file, because you end up loading a bunch of class definitions that might not even be needed by your script (i.e.: script A might need it, but not script B, however they end up loading it anyway).

PHP 5.3 (and a PECL extension for 5.2) introduced [PHARs](http://php.net/phar) (PHP Archives), which works a little like JARs (Java equivalent):

```
$phar = new Phar('myLibrary.phar');
$phar->addFile('myClass.php');
```

Then you can do:

```
include_once('phar://myLibrary.phar/myClass.php');
```

I use it often and it is indeed very useful for quick software updates on client/production servers.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of anything like that before, but maybe this could help... not really sure how it works http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/PHP-Clases/Split-and-merge-files-19891.html

Answer (score 0):

It is a new extension built-in PHP 5.3. You can read more about it here
http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php